# How to pin modern ie to the taskbar?

Tags: windows-8.1, internet-explorer, modern-ui, pin

Regarding the new Windows 8.1 Update 1's ability to pin modern apps to the task bar, I have a problem - I cannot pin the modern IE to the taskbar. When I right click and set "Pin to taskbar" it pins the desktop ie, not the modern one.

How do I pin the modern IE to the taskbar?

Comment: I'd bet it's because MS expects you to use the desktop IE while on the desktop.